# Social bike race costume - Morph Suits

Tags: clothes

I've had a blast at a social mountain bike race/relay the other week.  Our corporate team wants to do it again next year, and in costume too.

Question is:  Do you think these all-over costumes would work acceptably on an off-road bike race?  I'm mostly concerned about visibility (the rider seeing out) and slightly worried about sweat and bunching.

Further details: Lap times were 30-35 minutes, so its not a sprint relay.  The track was a mostly flat and dry singletrack with some shingle 4wd track.  Downtime between laps was while 2x 3x 4x laptime, while other people did their lap.

http://www.morphsuits.co.nz/morphsuits/original-morphsuit

http://www.trademe.co.nz/971555375

http://www.trademe.co.nz/968518586

[image]

[image]

Comment: This depends somewhat on where you live. There are places (e.g. France) where this would be illegal, to begin with.

Comment: @batman interesting point - what part makes it illegal in France, that the face is covered like a mask?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I would look for other alternatives.

These suits are very "one general size" type. Meaning they don't fit very well and have quite a bit of chafing as a possibility. I wore one for a fun 10K a few years back and I am glad I wore my trainer undies with them. I got chaffing around the armpits and the visibility was such that I wouldn't want to be on a single track course. If you must pick a theme to do this event, skip the morph suits.

*IMHO*
Mountain bike racing and the general silliness of a themed event poses several safety challenges. Usually people are less inclined to take their surroundings into account when their having fun. Add that with trail conditions and people on mountain bikes and I think you'd be asking for collisions and crashes.

Comment: Thanks for reporting your experience. Having people willing to say "I did this so you don't have to" is extremely useful.